# Angular-formly trying to get api-check from a non-existing source

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-formly

I'm trying to add [angular-formly](http://angular-formly.com/) to my AngularJs application using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). I've added

```
'apiCheck': '../vendor/api-check/dist/api-check',
'formly': '../vendor/angular-formly/dist/formly',
```

and added shim;

```
'formly': {
exports: 'formly',
deps: ['angular', 'apiCheck']
},
```

But, when I look at the network, it gets both of the libraries by making correct calls. However, it creates another request (probably formly doing this) to get apiCheck from `http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/api-check.js` addess. 
So far, I have tried to add apiCheck in shim and removing it from the formly dependencies etc.

How can I avoid this? It does not allow my application to run. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem. It turns out that formly looks for api-check and I've defined dependency as apiCheck. Changing main.js like this worked;

```
'api-check': '../vendor/api-check/dist/api-check',

'formly': {
    exports: 'formly',
    deps: ['angular', 'api-check']
},
```